# Modify TIMESTAMP to reflect correct TIMEZONE

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

So I am trying submit a timestamp into my MySQL table.  It is doing it successfully using this line of code, however the time zone is incorrect.  Anybody have ideas as to what needs to happen to ensure the timestamp is updated to reflect America/New York?

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" id="hiddenField" value=<?php $query = "UPDATE ApparatusTrouble SET _submitted_ = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ";
```

Comment: Are you really passing an arbitrary SQL statement in a hidden field? http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Be sure to read the MySQL docs on [the `TIMESTAMP` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and on [time zone support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to control the timezone as it's stored in the database. The timestamp will be the current time in UTC, which is to say that it's a globally understood and timezone-independent timestamp.

If you want to display the time as being in New York time, that's a question for your display logic: retrieve the UTC timestamp from the database, then convert it to New York time and display it.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP storing without timezone, timezone applying by mysql server when you retriving data from Mysql, so you need properly set timezone for you mysql connection like this,

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Better practice is set +00:00 for connection, and after aplying timezone on client in begin  php script for example

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using PHP to generate the timestamp if you could I would stick to using UTC (it avoids time zone confusion).

Also, the way you're doing it the client could modify the form data and submit the SQL which is not the safest way to design your code (in case you didn't know).

Also, if you generate a timestamp while PHP is processing and load it into a hidden form variable it's going to have the date of when PHP processed the form and not the time that the form was submitted.

IE.

Somewhere in the submitted form action in PHP...

```
<?php
...

date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); //Available since PHP 5.1

//see php date manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
// not sure what format CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is set to in your SQL server
  $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
  $query = 'UPDATE ApparatusTrouble SET _submitted_ = ' . $now . ';';

...
?>
```